# Connect a Google Cloud VM to Colab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-colaboratory

I'm struggling to connect a VM machine from Google Cloud to Colab.
Step done:
I've created a Colab instance in the Deployment Manager
In Colab I provided the the project id, the Colab instance zone and the instance name.
Even if I try with the button "CONNECT TO VM WITH COLAB" it's not working.
Is it a bug or I didn't do something as it should be
Thanks.

Step done is described above

Comment: Note: I also have a Colab Pro+ subscription